# Webpack warning entrypoint size limit bundle.js

Tags: angular, webpack

**Issue**

In my Angular2 node application this warning appears without making any changes to my application,

**Warning**

> WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the
>   recommended size limit (250 kB). This can impact web performance.
>   Assets:   bundle.js (10.3 MB)
>
> WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined
>   asset size exceeds the recommended limit (250 kB). This can impact web
>   performance. Entrypoints:   app (10.3 MB)
>         bundle.js
>
> WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: You can limit the size
>   of your bundles by using System.import() or require.ensure to lazy
>   load some parts of your application. For more info visit
>   https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

**Background**

I am concerned with what the problem is. To understand it and how to fix it before it comes to needing a solution. My thought is that my design pattern is flawed.

**Question**

**1.** By changing the design pattern or architecture is this problem avoidable?

**2.** If so then how?

**3.** What exactly makes the application too large when this error is thrown?

**4.** Does this warning effect the application when it is in production, or only in development when using `Webpack` to build the project?

Comment: Maybe this might be interesting for you: https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack/issues/90

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- More about this can be found at : https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3216
- If you want to disable this warning :

  ```
  performance : {
      hints : false
  }
  ```
- If you want to fix the issue : It was given in more detail in the above link. To simply put :

  - Use Lazy Loading of modules (this makes sure that we load some sections only if user visits that page)
  - List out which files are having more size and find a strategy to split them or reduce it's size.
  - Example to Strategy of splitting files : If we are using jQuery, Bootstrap and Fontawesome, then instead of packing all those into a single big file separate them using `entry points` in webpack.
  - Example to reduce files size : If we are using Bootstrap : Are we really using all of Bootstrap? If not, use some loader like `bootstrap-loader` which will allow us to selectively on/off features/files/functionalities from bootstrap.
  - Of course above strategies purely depends on what are the libraries that you are using in your application. I just took some examples.

Comment: For readers using Webpack 5: For splitting library, please take a look at [SplitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/).